# Perl Conditions

Tags: string, perl, loops, conditional-statements

Trying to iterate through two files. Everything works although once I get to the negation of my if statement it messes everything up. The only thing that will print is the else statement
Please disregard any unused variables, when defined. Will clean it up after.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
#   Packages and modules
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use version;   our $VERSION = qv('5.16.0');   # This is the version of Perl to be used
use Text::CSV  1.32;   # We will be using the CSV module (version 1.32 or higher)
                       # to parse each line

#
#   readFile.pl
#      Authors: schow04@mail.uoguelph + anilam@mail.uoguelph.ca
#      Project: Lab Assignment 1 Script (Iteration 0)
#      Date of Last Update: Monday, November 16, 2015.
#
#      Functional Summary
#         readFile.pl takes in a CSV (comma separated version) file 
#         and prints out the fields.  
#         There are three fields:
#            1. name
#            2. gender (F or M)
#            3. number of people with this name  
#
#         This code will also count the number of female and male 
#         names in this file and print this out at the end.
#
#         The file represents the names of people in the population 
#         for a particular year of birth in the United States of America.  
#         Officially it is the "National Data on the relative frequency 
#         of given names in the population of U.S. births where the individual 
#         has a Social Security Number".
#
#      Commandline Parameters: 1
#         $ARGV[0] = name of the input file containing the names
#
#      References
#         Name files from http://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/limits.html
#

#
#   Variables to be used
#
my $EMPTY = q{};
my $SPACE = q{ };
my $COMMA = q{,};
my $femalecount = 0;
my $malecount = 0;
my $lines = 0;
my $filename     = $EMPTY;

my $filename2    = $EMPTY;
my @records;
my @records2;
my $record_count = -1;
my $top_number = 0;
my $male_total = 0;
my $male_count   = 0;
my @first_name;
my @gender;
my @first_name2;
my @number;
my $count = 0;
my $count2 = 0;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => $COMMA });

#
#   Check that you have the right number of parameters
#
if ($#ARGV != 1) {
   print "Usage: readTopNames.pl <names file> <course names file>\n" or
      die "Print failure\n";
   exit;
} 

 $filename = $ARGV[0];
 $filename2 = $ARGV[1];


#
#   Open the input file and load the contents into records array
#
open my $names_fh, '<', $filename
   or die "Unable to open names file: $filename\n";

@records = <$names_fh>;

close $names_fh or
   die "Unable to close: $ARGV[0]\n";   # Close the input file

open my $names_fh2, '<', $filename2
   or die "Unable to open names file: $filename2\n";

@records2 = <$names_fh2>;

close $names_fh2 or
   die "Unable to close: $ARGV[1]\n";   # Close the input file

#
#   Parse each line and store the information in arrays 
#   representing each field
#
#   Extract each field from each name record as delimited by a comma
#


foreach my $class_record (@records)
{
   chomp $class_record;
   $record_count = 0;
   $count = 0;
   foreach my $name_record ( @records2 )
   {
      if ($csv->parse($name_record))
      {
         my @master_fields = $csv->fields();
         $record_count++;
         $first_name[$record_count] = $master_fields[0];
         $gender[$record_count]     = $master_fields[1];
         $number[$record_count]     = $master_fields[2];

         if($class_record eq $first_name[$record_count])
         {
            if($gender[$record_count] eq 'F')
            {
               print("$first_name[$record_count] ($record_count)\n");
            }
            if($gender[$record_count] eq 'M')
            {
               my $offset = $count - 2224;
               print("$first_name[$record_count] ($offset)\n");
            }
         } 

      } else {
         warn "Line/record could not be parsed: $records[$record_count]\n";
      }
      $count++;
   }
}







#
#   End of Script
#

Adam (187)
Alan (431)
Alejandro (1166)
Alex (120)
Alicia (887)
Ambrose (305)
Caleb (794)
```

Sample output from running the following code.
This is correct: Although if a name is not found in the second file it is supposed to say:

```
Adam (187)
Alan (431)
Name (0)
Alejandro (1166)
Alex (120)
Alicia (887)
Ambrose (305)
Caleb (794)
```

That is what the else is supposed to find. Whether the if statement returned nothing.

```
else {
      print("$first_name[$record_count] (0)\n");
         }
```

The output that i get when i add that else, to account for the negation is literally:

```
Elzie (0)
Emer (0)
Enna (0)
Enriqueta (0)
Eola (0)
Eppie (0)
Ercell (0)
Estellar (0)
```

Comment: which `if`? which `else`?

Comment: That doesn't run. Please provide the missing bits.

Comment: if($class_record eq $first_name[$record_count])
that part, i take out the else, it works, without the else it doesn't.

Comment: You need to start by naming your variables properly. For instance, you have `$record_count`, `$count` and `$counter`. Even you probably don't know what they're all counting, as `$counter` is incremented twice for each iteration of `@records2` but otherwise unused. `@records` appears to be a list of first names, because the iterator `$class_record` is compared in `$class_record eq $first_name[$record_count]` but there is also a `@records2` which also says nothing about what it might cointain. I'm not surprised you're confused!

Comment: it should be `foreach my $name_record (@records2){ $record_count++;...}` as I mentioned in the answer. it is where you put `$record_count++`.

Comment: Did that although, all it prints is "Bad", there is no occurrence of the first condition ever.

`   foreach my $name_record ( @records2 )
   {
      $record_count++;`

Comment: @AmbroseNilam, I updated my answer, it should able to address your issue

Comment: And the contents of the input text files are...? Nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1):

It's really tough to help you properly without better information, so I've written this, which looks for each name from the names file in the master data file and displays the associated values

There's never a reason to write a long list of declarations like that at the top of a program, and you've written way too much code before you started debugging. You should write no more than three or four lines of code before you test that it works and carry on adding to it. You've ended up with 140 lines — mostly of them comments — that don't do what you want, and you're now lost as to what you should fix first

I haven't been able to fathom what all your different counters are for, or why you're subtracting a magic 2224 for male records, so I've just printed the data directly from the master file

I hope you'll agree that it's far clearer with the variables declared when they're required instead of making a huge list at the top of your program. I've dropped the arrays `@first_name`, `@gender` and `@number` because you were only ever using the latest value so they had no purpose

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.16.0;
use autodie;

use Text::CSV;

STDOUT->autoflush;

if ( @ARGV != 2 ) {
    die "Usage: readTopNames.pl <names file> <master names file>\n";
}

my ( $names_file, $master_file ) = @ARGV;

my @names = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $names_file;
    <$fh>;
};
chomp @names;

my @master_data = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $master_file;
    <$fh>;
};
chomp @master_data;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;

for my $i ( 0 .. $#names ) {

    my $target_name = $names[$i];
    my $found;

    for my $j ( 0 .. $#master_data ) {

        my $master_rec = $master_data[$j];
        my $status     = $csv->parse($master_rec);

        unless ( $status ) {
            warn qq{Line/record "$master_rec" could not be parsed\n};
            next;
        }

        my ( $name, $gender, $count ) = $csv->fields;

        if ( $name eq $target_name ) {

            $found = 1;

            printf "%s %s (%d)\n", $name, $gender, $count;
        }
    }

    unless ( $found ) {
        printf "%s (%d)\n", $target_name, 0;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
Adam F (7)
Adam M (5293)
Alan F (9)
Alan M (2490)
Name (0)
Alejandro F (6)
Alejandro M (2593)
Alex F (157)
Alex M (3159)
Alicia F (967)
Ambrose M (87)
Caleb F (14)
Caleb M (9143)
```

Answer (score -1):

4 changes proposed:

```
foreach my $class_record (@records)
{
    chomp $class_record;
    $record_count = 0;
    $count = 0;

    # add found - modification A
    my $found = 0;

    foreach my $name_record ( @records2 )
    {
        # should not be here
        #$record_count++;
        if ($csv->parse($name_record))
        {
            my @master_fields = $csv->fields();
            $record_count++;
            $first_name[$record_count] = $master_fields[0];
            $gender[$record_count]     = $master_fields[1];
            $number[$record_count]     = $master_fields[2];

            if($class_record eq $first_name[$record_count])
            {
                if($gender[$record_count] eq 'F')
                {
                    print("$first_name[$record_count] ($record_count)\n");
                }
                if($gender[$record_count] eq 'M')
                {
                    my $offset = $count - 2224;
                    print("$first_name[$record_count] ($offset)\n");
                }
                # modification B - set found =1
                $found = 1;
                #last;    # no need to keep looping
                next; # find next one if try to find more than 1
            }

        } else {
            warn "Line/record could not be parsed: $records[$record_count]\n";
        }
        $count++;
    }

    # modification C -
    if($found){
    }else{
        print "${class_record}(0)\n";
    }
}
```